# I want to select array elements using command prompt using JavaScript and when you select element that element is change to 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

For example:
var seatnum= [1,2,3,4,5];
I want to select a seatnum through command prompt
Select your seatnum;
5
Then seatnum 5 change to 0 because this seatnum selected
Then output seatnum [1,2,3,4,0 ];

Comment: You efforts till now ?

Comment: I am just learning JavaScript now I want to practice something different.So I don't know how to give input from the command prompt

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prompt` like this to receive input from user.

```js
let arr = [...'123456'];

const select = prompt('Select seat number')

const output = arr.map(e=> (e === select ? '0' : e) )

console.log(output)
```

I suggest you to read more about [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) here

Comment: Tq sir,  I have doubt how can I fill colour to selected array element

Comment: @MEESALAPRANITH that's a very broad thing to explain. i suggest you to go bit by bit, learn basic js html and css first, ( yes sure you can ) .

Comment: Ok sir Thank you for your response.